# A word for going out in your own way

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Are there any words or idiom that means like dying the way you want or dying of your own free will? I'm thinking kinda like some sort of more honorable suicide or kinda like you know you're going to die if you do something but the alternative is worse, like a word for sacrifice that specifically means dying.

Comment: The single word would seem to be ***suicide***. Is there a reason that doesn't work for you? Are there other options you've looked at that aren't quite right? Also, how do you want to use the term? The more details you can give us about your previous research and what you're after, the better or answers will be.

Comment: I'm thinking kinda like some sort of more honorable suicide or kinda like you know you're going to die if you do something but the alternative is worse, like a word for sacrifice that specifically means dying.

Comment: The two circumstances you describe are differentiated by law in the US. The second one, where a terminally ill person wants a dignified end, is still a terminology minefield in the US. Different style guides handle the issue very differently. There is no consensus on how to describe these actions, and the noisy extremists are basically at war over how the media portrays it. [Here](https://www.deathwithdignity.org/terminology/)'s a starting point. Good luck.

Comment: And I see you are collecting close votes. Please provide a sentence with a blank space which shows us how you intend to use the word. These are required for questions tagged 'single word requests'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*to die on your own terms*

examples:

> Working with Compassion & Choices, Maynard used her story to speak out for the right of terminally ill people like herself to end their lives on their own terms.

^ [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2014/nov/03/terminally-ill-oregon-death-with-dignity-brittany-maynard)

> They didn't want to lose her any earlier than they had to, but they accepted her choice to die on her own terms.

^ [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2001/dec/23/local/me-17424)

> Emphasis on individualism and autonomy typical of North American societies has produced a significant chorus of voices supporting a person’s “right-to-die” on his or her own terms.

^  [AMA Journal of Ethics](http://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/2017/08/msoc1-1708.html)

> David Bowie planned his end as he lived – on his own terms, blazing a trail

^ [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jan/12/david-bowie-death-end-of-life-plans-cancer)

> Dying on your own terms: A physician’s advice for a better death

^ [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2015/02/03/dying-on-your-own-terms-a-physicians-advice-for-a-better-death/)

some book titles:

*Life and Death on Your Own Terms*,   by Lofty Bosta, MD

*The Better End: Surviving (and Dying) on Your Own Terms in Today's Modern Medical World*,   by Dan Morhaim, MD

*Final Victory: Taking Charge of the Last Stanges of Life, Facing Death on Your Own Terms*,  by Thomas Preson, MD